# The enabled state of a plugin for a Google doc is lost when the document is copied - is it a bug?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, google-docs

If you install and addon in Google docs and open the side bar in a Google document, then this addon is noted as 'enabled' for the document.

This means that another user opening the same document will see the sidebar opening if the addon is programmed to do so. That happens because an enabled plugin is opened by Google docs with state AuthMode.LIMITED.

All this is defined in : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle

It seems that now, when one does a 'make copy' in Google drive, the copied document loses the enabled state for the addon.

I tested it by installing the 'table of contents add on' and clicking : 'always open for this document' : the sidebar opens with the document, but if one makes a copy of the doc in Google Drive, this behavior is lost. Now the user must manually start the addon on the copied document.

**This is new, it wasn't that way a month ago.**

*Is it a bug ? Or a new security feature ?
How can I copy the 'enabled' property of the addon to a document ?*

Comment: I wouldn't expect that any authorization or document setting would be copied to a new document. Did this behaviour used to happen? It would be handy to see a screen video of it... I don't trust my own memory that much.

Answer (score 0):

As said Mogshad in the comment above one expects documents settings to be copied along with the document.

**->**  I see since Friday afternoon that the issue mentionned in this post is resolved. The enabled state is copied again, probably because of a silent bugfix.

Still we didn't dream it as we saw it during the week on production environments on which nothing has changed.